# Concatenation on the basis of distinct values

Tags: excel

```
A   B
richa   singh
niddhi  dutta
akash   jain
richa   sharma
akash   shekhar
```

Hi I have data in two columns A and B.I want my output like this

```
A   B
richa   singh,sharma
niddhi  dutta
akash   jain,shekhar
```

I am a beginner,please suggest some formula which I can use to get the desired output

Comment: Can you reformat this in columns? I can't follow precisely what output you expect

Comment: @doctorlove thanks for editing my question:)

Comment: For future reference - there's some format buttons e.g. `{}` for code layout.

Comment: Alright,will use them...

Comment: Can you help me with this question,which formula and how should I use it to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I think here there is explained what you are trying to do:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2723-excel-concatenate-based-on-criteria.html

According to this tutorial, there is not any single formula to do that, but they explain it in 6 simple steps.